# How to use sphinx plugin for MySQL to implement fulltext search with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, code-snippets

Can someone provide a demo here?

And how to retrieve the matching snippet at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

It's written in the docs :)

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse-using

Comment: I've installed the sphinx plugin for MySQL on windows,how to test its functionalities?